# Add HyperLink to PowerPoint slide using office.js

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I need to insert a hyperLink to PowerPoint slide using [office.js](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office?product=powerpoint)
How we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported, PowerPoint only supports inserting `text` and this would require supporting `html`. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.